# How to prevent deadlock of table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table were values can be altered by different users and records of 100k rows.

I made a stored procedure where in, it has a begin tran and at the last part
to either commit or rollback the changes depending on the situation.

So for now the problem we're encountering is a lock of that table. For example 1st user is executing the stored procedure thru the system, then the other users won't be able to select or also execute the stored procedure because the table is currently locked.

So is there anyway where I can avoid lock other than using dirty read. Or a way where I can rollback the changes made without using begin tran, because it is the main reason why the table is locked up.

Comment: Show us the SP. One cause of deadlock is a long running transaction caused by suboptimal SP.

Comment: It was so long and the whole process is done by 2 sp. But we already optimized the code to make it faster.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't typically lock the entire table - it locks on a **row level** first. Only if your transaction is trying to apply more than 5000 updates (or deletes, or inserts), then SQL Server will escalate to a table lock......

Comment: Usually we're updating 1000 rows simultaneously per user.

Comment: there are many cases that you can resolve deadlock by reordering your DML operations (if possible). For example, if in process 1 you update T1 and then T2, and in other process you update T2 and then T1, you increase the possibility of deadlock. In such cases if you can update T1 and then T2 in both process, you'll resolve the deadlock issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can at least (quick & dirty) enable `SNAPSHOT` isolation level for transactions. That will prevent locks inside the transactions.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

[See](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: It's safe. Every data modification statement within a transaction that modifies the rows that were altered by another transactions since the time current transaction started will cause an error (optimistic concurrency). However, enabling snapshot isolation can increase I\O load and `tempdb` size in some scenarios, therefore, hurting overall database performance.